# How to use value of var which is set inside .then() outside of .then()?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I want to use a value of a var that is set inside of `.then()` in the outer scope

*I tried*

```js
let numOfDropdownFields = 0;
cy.get("dropdown")
  .find("button")
  .its("length")
  .as("len")
  .then(($len) => {
    cy.log("No. of buttons:" + $len);
    numOfDropdownFields = $len;
    cy.get("@len").should("eq", numOfDropdownFields);
    cy.log(numOfDropdownFields);
  });
cy.log(numOfDropdownFields);
```

*The first log prints*:
No. of elements: 14

*The second log*: 14

*And the third log*: 0

How can I see the value 14 outside the `.then()` callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is considered an antipattern in cypress. Generally you should do everything you want to do with that Variable inside the `.then()`.
Make sure to use Syntax like: `.then() => {all your code in here}`.

Look here for Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases

Also you can Use Aliases like you already did with `.as('len')`.

Answer (score 1):

Each `cy.something()` function call is setting up a command in the Cypress queue.

Commands that access the DOM like `cy.get()` and `cy.find()` take time to process, so you can think of them in the same way as promises, running asynchronously from the javascript in the test code.

The `cy.log(numOfDropdownFields)` line is actually executed before `.its("length")` happens, and at that time it grabs the current value of `numOfDropdownFields` which is 0.

But Cypress executes the commands in the queue in the order they were added, so the log ***appears*** to happen after the length code is run.

Just change `cy.log()` for `console.log()` and you will see the proper order of events.

This is the whole reason for the alias mechanism - it provides an alternate way to "wait" for the command queue to catch up.

```js
let numOfDropdownFields = 0;
cy.get("dropdown")
  .find("button")
  .its("length")
  .as("len")
  .then(($len) => {
    cy.log("No. of buttons:" + $len);                   // > 0
    console.log('I log second', $len);                  // > 0
    numOfDropdownFields = $len;
  cy.get("@len").should("eq", numOfDropdownFields);
  cy.log(numOfDropdownFields);                          // > 0
});
cy.log(numOfDropdownFields)                             // === 0
console.log('I log first', numOfDropdownFields);        // === 0
cy.get('@len').then(() => cy.log(numOfDropdownFields))  // > 0
```